# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hsSideNav is not a function, with webpacker in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have a Rails 6 application working with the asset pipeline, which I'm trying to move to webpacker in order to use turbo. So far I've managed to correctly set up turbo. The app uses some bootstrap plugins though, hsSideNav among them, and I'm getting an error I haven't been able to solve: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hsSideNav`.

I've placed a copy of the hsSideNav file in `app/javascript/hs-navbar-vertical-aside/hs-navbar-vertical-aside.js`.

Here's my `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
require("hs-navbar-vertical-aside/hs-navbar-vertical-aside")
```

And my `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    jQuery: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to load jQuery plugins in webpacker?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem with hsSideNav/webpacker.